# how to parse html on jsfiddle via console.log

Tags: jsfiddle

### jsfiddle [demo](http:////jsfiddle.net/lyu0001/gvzsr2aj/17/)

(correct version)

I want to extract HTML content via console.log and show on the display screen. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const extract_heading = document.querySelector('#heading').innerHTML;
const extract_content = document.querySelector('.container-content').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks, I forget to change 'doc' to 'document'.